# How to implement SOAP Web service with SWIFT programming language?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am very new to swift language I need to implement SOAP Web service in SWIFT programming language. I got a sample code from gitHub

> https://github.com/rubelbd82/soapwithswift but unfortunately this is not working so anyone help me where is the mistake . my SOAP message is 
>   http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx?op=FahrenheitToCelsius

Answer (score 1):

Read http://webindream.com/soap-with-swift/

You've to just change from NSURLConnection to NSURLSession in Swift 3

Comment: yes i did but cant parse see my changed code i have attached

Answer (score 0):

```
static func callAPI(strUrl: String, soapMsg : String ,param: NSDictionary?, mediaData : NSData? , strAction : String,completion : @escaping (JSON) -> ()){

    UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()

    let soapLenth = String(soapMsg.characters.count)
    let theURL = NSURL(string: strUrl)
    let mutableR = NSMutableURLRequest(url: theURL! as URL)

    mutableR.addValue("text/xml; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    mutableR.addValue("text/html; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    // mutableR.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    mutableR.addValue("www.w3schools.com", forHTTPHeaderField: "Host")
    mutableR.addValue(soapLenth, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    mutableR.addValue("https://tempuri.org/"+"\(strAction)", forHTTPHeaderField: "SOAPAction")
    mutableR.httpMethod = "POST"
    mutableR.httpBody = soapMsg.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

    let manager = AFHTTPSessionManager()
    manager.requestSerializer.timeoutInterval=180
    manager.responseSerializer=AFHTTPResponseSerializer()
    // manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes=NSSet(array: ["text/xml"]) as? Set<String>

    let task = manager.dataTask(with: mutableR as URLRequest, uploadProgress: nil, downloadProgress: nil) { (response, responseObject, error) in

        if (error == nil){
            let str=NSString(data: responseObject as! Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            let data = str!.components(separatedBy: "<?")[0].data(using: String.Encoding(rawValue: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue))!
            jsonData=JSON(data: data)
            MBProgressHUD.hide(for: view, animated: true)
            UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
            if jsonData != nil{

                completion(jsonData)
            }
        }
        else{
            MBProgressHUD.hide(for: view, animated: true)
            self.view.makeToast(error!.localizedDescription)
            UIApplication.shared.endIgnoringInteractionEvents()
            completion(JSON(data: NSData() as Data))
        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

**call above function**

```
let soapMessage = NSString(format: "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><soap:Body><FahrenheitToCelsius xmlns=\"https://tempuri.org/\"><Fahrenheit>%@</Fahrenheit></FahrenheitToCelsius></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>", "25")

APIS.callAPI(strUrl: "http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx", soapMsg: soapMessage as String, param: nil, mediaData : nil ,strAction: "FahrenheitToCelsius", completion: { (JSON) in
  print(JSON)
})
```

Comment: Amit jagesha oki will try.

Comment: amit jagesh. i have attached my code , I need to pass user name and password my output is not JASON i am geting as XML.please try my new code i have attached .I didnt get any output

Answer (score 0):

```
 @IBAction func actionConvert(_ sender : AnyObject) {

    let soapMessage = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap12='http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope'><soap12:Body><TD_UserLogin xmlns='http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.com/xml/'><LoginName>\(usernam)</LoginName><Password>\(pass)</Password></TD_UserLogin></soap12:Body></soap12:Envelope>"

    let urlString = "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.asmx"

    let url = URL(string: urlString)

    let theRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url!)

    let msgLength = soapMessage.characters.count

    theRequest.addValue("text/xml; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    theRequest.addValue(String(msgLength), forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
    theRequest.httpMethod = "POST"
    theRequest.httpBody = soapMessage.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false) // or false

    let connection = NSURLConnection(request: theRequest as URLRequest, delegate: self, startImmediately: true)
    connection!.start()

    print( "soap message is = \(soapMessage)")


    if (connection != nil) {
        var mutableData : Void = NSMutableData.initialize()
        print("Problem")
    }
    else {
        print("theConnection is NULL")
    }

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


// NSURLConnectionDelegate

// NSURL



func connection(_ connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveResponse response: URLResponse!) {
    mutableData.length = 0;
}

func connection(_ connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveData data: Data!) {
    mutableData.append(data)
}


func connectionDidFinishLoading(_ connection: NSURLConnection!) {
    let response = NSString(data: mutableData as Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

    let xmlParser = XMLParser(data: mutableData as Data)
    xmlParser.delegate = self
    xmlParser.parse()
    xmlParser.shouldResolveExternalEntities = true
}


// NSXMLParserDelegate


func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {
    currentElementName = elementName as NSString
    print( "curent element = \(currentElementName)")
}


func parser(_ parser: XMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
    if currentElementName == "TD_AuthenticateUserResponse" {
       //log
    }
}
}
```